# Map value is being overriden in java

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm trying to add different values for same key in a map and then store it in a list and code is below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> mainMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    mainMap.put("1", "First");

    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        Map<String, Object> childMap = new HashMap<>();
        childMap.put("2", i);
        mainMap.put("1", childMap.get("2"));
        list.add(mainMap);
        System.out.println("mainMap:" + mainMap);
    }

    System.out.println("list:" + list);
}
```

Actual output:

```
mainMap:{1=1}
mainMap:{1=2}
mainMap:{1=3}
mainMap:{1=4}
mainMap:{1=5}
list:[{1=5}, {1=5}, {1=5}, {1=5}, {1=5}]
```

Expected output:

```
list:[{1=1}, {1=2}, {1=3}, {1=4}, {1=5}]
```

Is it possible to achieve this using Map and if yes please guide me.

Comment: you add the same `mainMap` to the list in each loop iteration. Create a new one each time. What's up with the `childmap`? It does nothing.

Comment: @Nexevis he/she wants a list of hashmaps.

Comment: The reason why the you print `1 = 5` for all of them is because you are modifying the same `Map` each iteration and adding the same thing to the `List` again.  You need to create a `new HashMap<>()` each iteration for your `mainMap` (like you did the for `childMap`).  If you modify the value of the `Map` _after_ it is added to `List` it will still change the one you added before.  Though this seems like an `X-Y` problem, I don't see why you need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Map` instance replaces the old value if a value with the same key is put into it as a `Map` can not store duplicate keys. Since you are putting iteration values against the same key into the same instance of `mainMap`, the new value is replacing the old one. You need to assign a new instance to `mainMap` every time you put into it an iteration value using the same key. The following code will give you a hint to proceed:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> map;
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("1", i);
            list.add(map);
        }
        System.out.println("list:" + list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
list:[{1=1}, {1=2}, {1=3}, {1=4}, {1=5}]
```

Comment: my original mainMap has other key values as well and this way i will lose the other values right?

Answer (score 0):

It would be not possible to achieve the desired result using `Map`. According to Java documentation:

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate
>   keys; each key can map to at most one value.
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

As an alternative, you may try to store a `List` in the `Map`, like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> mainMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<Object> childList = new ArrayList<>();
    mainMap.put("1", childList);
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        childList.add(i);
    }
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(mainMap);
    System.out.println("list:" + list);
}
```

**Output:**
`list:[{1=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}]`